# How To Get Flight Fares For An App

Tags: python, web-scraping

I was interested in making an iOS app that uses flight fares to help you find the cheapest flight. But I was wondering where sites like Kayak, Cheapflights, expedia, orbitz, and such get their flight information from? Because from what I have heard, scraping airline websites will not lead to go things, so how do they get airline information?

How can i go about getting airline fares?

Comment: you sign up for sabre or apollo (I think thats the other major GDS) and pay the fee to have API access ...   see http://www.sabre.com/

Comment: is there no other free way to do it? Like how does sabre get their flight information? There has to be some way everyone is getting their flight information

Comment: sabre pays directly to the airlines .... in order to have access to all their flight databases (source I was a travel agent for 10 years)